# Python list having length larger than expected

Tags: python, numpy

One would assume this has length `2*(60-18+1) = 86`, but it gives `100` when using `len(obj)`:

```
import numpy as np;
series = ['{0}{1:02d}'.format(gender,age) for gender in ['M','F'] for age in np.linspace(18,60,dtype=int)]
print(len(series))
```

The question is, why?

Comment: `len(np.linspace(18,60,dtype=int)) ` is 50, so your assumption is wrong

Answer (score 3):

NumPY's [`linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) has an optional third argument which is the amount of samples to pull from the start to finish, by default it is 50, and with 2 Genders it would generate 100. To change it to what amount you would like, add a third argument with the amount you want per gender.